# enable touch scrolling on usercontrol within a tablelayoutpanel (or any panel)

Tags: c#, winforms

Presently I am populating a `tablelayoutpanel` with `usercontrols`, when the `usercontrols` takes more space I have enable the `autoscroll` on the `tablelayoutpanel`. Obviously, I am able to scroll the `tablelayoutpanel` with a mouse or on the scrollbar. I want to be able to scroll with the TOUCH functionality on a tablet by dragging on the middle of the `tablelayoutpanel`. The problem is that I am able to scroll with touch on all the areas outside of the `usercontrols` but nothing happens when I try to touch scroll on the `usercontrols`.

I am wondering if someone have encountered that problem/design issue and how did you deal with it?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Any resolution for this, i know this is old but i have same issue...